# Constant time change first k elements of an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's suppose I have an array:

`bool eleme[1000000] = {false};`

and at some point in my code I change some of the first of the `n` elements of this array to `true`.
Afterwards I want to be sure that all elements of the array are `false`. So I do:

```
for (int i =0; i < n; ++i)     
       eleme[i] = false;
```

which costs `Θ(n)`.

Is there a way to do this in constant time? E.g. something like
`make_false(eleme, n);`

Comment: `std::fill(eleme, eleme+1000000, false);` is performed in constant time. Are you really asking for constant time, or are you really asking for "faster"?

Comment: I think it should be OK to set the underlying memory to zero (using `memset`), but look at the assembly if your compiler isn't doing that already anyway.

Comment: @Robᵩ Well I guess constant time is fasther than Theta(n). But i'm looking for faster

Comment: @Robᵩ: The classic O(100000) solution? Maybe we can get it down to O(250000) though ;-)

Comment: @Robᵩ But I want to do `fill(eleme, eleme + n, false);` Of course the solution `for (int i = 0; i <10000000; ++i) eleme[i] = false;` would also be `O(1)` but this is not what I mean.

Comment: So, what *do* you mean, @Johny96? Do you really mean "How can I make my program go faster?" The answer to that is to use `std::fill` or `memset` instead of the loop.

Comment: The question is "How can I make my program faster by making something in constant time. Is it possible or not?"

Comment: @Johny96: Making something constant time will not always make a program go faster. Constant time != High performance. And besides, the number of operations needed to set an arbitrary number of array elements will always be linear or approximately linear with the number of elements you want to fill.

Comment: @Johny96: Consider this analogy: what you're asking is the same as asking "Is it possible to eat `n` apples in constant time?" The answer is no. If it takes 20 bites to consume one apple, then consuming two apples requires 40 bites and consuming four apples requires 80 bites. You can't solve this problem in constant time unless `n` is a constant.

Answer (score 3):

**General Answer**
If you want to modify N elements in memory, that is ultimately going to be an O(N) operation, regardless of whether you can express it with a single command like `memset` or `std::fill`.

The operation will be considerably faster if you design the algorithm such that as much as possible of the array is in cache. Using optimised built-in commands like `memset` also helps speed it up.

---

**Suggestion 1**
However, there is an **old algorithmic trick for constant-time array initialisation**, which would work for your case (constant-time array resetting) as well – at the cost of significant extra memory use, though.

It goes as follows: In addition to the main array `A1`, you allocate a second array `A2` of the same length, and a stack `S`, also of size N. None of these structures need to be initialised (and merely allocating them arguably is an O(1) operation). You also need a stack pointer `SP`.

Initially the stack pointer is 0 (pointing to the bottom of the stack).

Whenever you make an entry in `A1`, say `A1[i]=j`, you set `A2[i]=SP`, `S[SP]=i` and increment `SP`.

If you want to check whether a certain entry `A1[i]` has been set, you look up `A2[i]`. If `A2[i]<SP`, i.e. less than the current value of the stack pointer, you know that the corresponding stack entry `SP[A2[i]]` must have been set by you before. If the value of that stack entry is `i`, `A1[i]` is a valid entry. Otherwise it was never initialised.

Now, in order to reset all entries of `A1`, you simply set the stack pointer back to 0. That is a constant-time operation.

I must admit I never encountered a situation in which I found this trick to be actually useful; usually `memset`, while not constant-time, is simply fast enough.

Gonzalo Navarro recently published a [note](http://www.dcc.uchile.cl/~gnavarro/ps/sccc12.pdf) in which he describes a further set of tricks to compress the extra arrays so they use less space while retaining the O(1) time bound.

---

**Suggestion 2**
An alternative possibility is to **reset values in a lazy fashion**, only when necessary. This takes advantage of the fact that at the time of reset, only *some of the first few* elements will actually have been used, as you describe.

This involves maintaining, in a variable, the index of the left-most element that hasn't been initialised (or reset during the most recent reset), and when element `A[i]` is to be set, initialising (or resetting) all elements between the left-most uninitialised one and `i`.

To access the element at index `i`, you check whether `i` is smaller than the left-most uninitialised one, in which case you return `A[i]`; otherwise it hasn't been initialised (or reset), so you return the initialisation value (probably 0) as a literal.

To reset the array, you simply set the index of the left-most uninitialised element back to 0, which is a constant-time operation.

Of course this means that changing an entry is now an O(N) operation, but if you typically only set the *first few* elements of the array, it will never become really expensive. Also note that the total cost of all operations between two resets is still also O(N), because each element will be reset no more than once.

Another important advantage is cache-friendliness: Each time an element is set, the range of elements that require initialisation is likely to be small, and more likely to be fully in cache than when resetting all elements at once.

In C++ it may look something like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, T init_val>
class FastResetArray
{
  std::array<T,N> _data;                // the array
  unsigned        _min_uninitialised;   // the left-most non-initialised element
public:
  FastResetArray()
    :_data(),_min_uninitialised(0)
  {}

  T at(const unsigned index) {
    return (index < _min_uninitialised ? _data[index] : init_val);
  }

  void set(const unsigned index, const T val) {
    if (index > _min_uninitialised)
      std::fill_n(begin(_data) + _min_uninitialised,
          index - _min_uninitialised,
          init_val);
    _data[index] = val;
    _min_uninitialised = index + 1;
  }

  void reset() {
    _min_uninitialised = 0;
  }
};
```

(Note that in the constructor, I set `_min_uninitialised` (the index of the left-most uninitialised element) to 0. Since the default constructor of `std::array` initialises the entire array to zero anyway, I could as well set to `N` if `init_val` is zero. So the implementation above does not help to avoid the initial O(N) initialisation – we only avoid O(N) in `reset()`.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this in constant time [and not visit more than `n` elements]?

No. You have to set `n` elements, that will take `n` steps, thus O(n).

You can make it go faster by not writing the loop by hand. I think you'll discover that:

```
std::fill(eleme, eleme+n, false);
```

goes faster than

```
for (int i =0; i < n; ++i)     
   eleme[i] = false;
```

even though they have the same big-O complexity.

Comment: It's not so obvious that because I want to set n elements I need n steps. Because I want to set n continuous elements to `false`. Perhaps the compiler/hardware has tricks to bypass this and can do it in constant time?

Comment: @Johny96: Why are you so concerned with doing this in constant time? The fact that something has constant or linear time complexity says nothing about how fast it will perform in practice.

Answer (score 1):

According to

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time

Your code already is already constant time

if the number of elements is known in advance and does not change

which seems to be true from the declaration

bool eleme[1000000] = {false};

Answer (score 0):

If the number of elements in your array is n (not constant), initializing all of the values in that array to be false will always be in linear time. HOWEVER, if you think about it, if this array is part of some larger algorithm, you can usually find a different way to solve your problem in constant time (I'm making this assumption because if you're initializing all of the elements in the array to 'false', then you must not care about the data currently being stored there, so why do anything with it at this point?).